# Problems launching rocon chatter concert inside of a Docker image

Tags: ros, docker, rocon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a simple rocon concert working inside of a Docker instance with my limited knowledge of rocon and avahi.

I started from [this Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/rayman/ros-indigo-ros-base) which provides the base ROS installation and got rocon_tutorials from the the apt repos there. I verified I can successfully run basic ROS nodes and configurations. Unfortunately, when trying to run [the rocon chatter concert](http://wiki.ros.org/chatter_concert/Tutorials/Chatter%20Concert) I get some issues which I am having trouble getting past.

The most relevant symptom is that all consoles spawned by the rocon launch show the following error:

> [ERROR] [1424808531.546619171]: Zeroconf: failed to create an avahi client.

after which everything else fails.

I have tried several things including running avahi manually inside the docker container, making sure to start the docker container in privileged mode, etc.

Any guidance on how to further tackle the problem, or any general hints on getting the environment right for rocon would be greatly appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203725/problems-launching-rocon-chatter-concert-inside-of-a-docker-image/) by [jcerruti](https://answers.ros.org/users/19864/jcerruti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like docker does not support avahi-daemon properly. And it causes a problem in zero configuration.

I have proposed a patch to use rocon without zero configuration in https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_concert/pull/272

With this patch, you should be able to run chatter concert without zeroconf failure.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcerruti](https://answers.ros.org/users/19864/jcerruti/) on 2015-02-26**:
Thank you jihoonl, this lets us run rocon inside Docker. I can confirm it works.